# replace words /strings by bold word/string

Tags: c#, regex, string, winforms, replace

Based in this[replace multiple words by the same word in bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247338/replace-multiple-words-by-the-same-word-in-bold/27294319#27294319) , I realised that this code has a problem/limitation ..

```
    public string MakeBold(string text, string[] splitwords)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var words = text.Split(" ");   
    sb.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi");
    foreach (var word in words){
      if (splitwords.Contains(word)){
         sb.Append(@"\b"+word+ @"\b0 ");
      }
      else
      {
         sb.Append(word);
         sb.Append(@" ");
      }
    }
    sb.Append(@"}");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

With this line   `var words = text.Split(" ");`    I´m separating all the words in the text, but what if the string I want to replace is :

Text: "I have a text and I need to put some words in bold"

Words: "have a text";  "bold"

Result : "I **have a text** and I need to put some words in **bold**"

EDIT ::

I updated my code like this

```
  private string Bold(string text, string[] splitwords)
   {

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

       builder.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi");

       foreach (string word in splitwords)
       {
               if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"(?<![\w])" + word + @"(?![\w])" ))
           {
               text= text.Replace(word, @"\b " + word + " " + @"\b0");
               }
       }

       builder.Append(text);
       builder.Append(@"}");

       return builder.ToString();
   }
```

But if the if I have the text

Text: "I have a text and I need to put some words in bold"

Words:  "have"; "have a text";  "bold"

Result : "I **have** a text and I need to put some words in **bold**"

But in another cases it works fine
HELP....

Comment: You can also use RichTextBox control to set part of your text bold. Like this:             RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
            rtb.Select(2, 2);
            rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(rtb.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

Comment: You want to search "have a text" as phrase in the Text or you want to search each word in Text? Also do you want to make the phrase itself bold or again few words?

Comment: @Siva Gopal : I want to search "have a text" as a phrase in a text. I want the phrase itself bold. The search depends on the Words I previously selected ( words or phrases)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    public string MakeBold(string text, string[] splitwords)
    {
        string returnValue = text;
        foreach (var word in splitwords)
        {
            returnValue = returnValue.Replace(word, @"\b" + word + @"\b0");
        }
        var finalString = new StringBuilder();
        finalString.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi");
        finalString.Append(returnValue);
        finalString.Append(@"}");
        return finalString.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: If I use your code the result I get is "I a textand I need to put some words in "

Answer (score 0):

We can check for all occurrences of each phrase:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
string[] words = text.Split(" ");
foreach (string phrase in splitwords)
{
    string[] phrasewords = phrase.Split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - phrasewords.Length; i++)
    {
        bool match = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < phrasewords.Length; j++)
            if (words[i] != phrasewords[j])
            {
                match = false;
                break;
            }

        if (match)
        {
            builder.Append(@"\b" + phrase + @"\b0 ");
            i += phrasewords.Length - 1;
        }
        else
            builder.Append(words[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

This won't work for overlapping phrases, e.g. "one two" and "two three".

Comment: what will you do if "text" string repeating in string I mean if Text="I have a text and I need to put some words in bold & also have some a..."